# how to pluck a converted array to collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I converted this array to a collection

```
array:1 [
"params" => array:3 [
"total_amount" => "2.37"
"user_id" => 3
"used_currency" => "YER"
]
]
```

```
$items = collect(request()->all());
```

How will I pluck the total_amount value when I converted it to a collection.

```
dd($items->get('params.total_amount'));
```

Comment: use this one $value =$items->pluck(['total_amount']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the array key on the collection

```php
dd($items->get('params')['total_amount']);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have converted only outer array to collection not to inner array.

To convert all array to collection use `json_decode` after `json_encode`.

```
$abc =  [
    "params" => [
        "total_amount" => "2.37",
        "user_id" => 3,
        "used_currency" => "YER"
    ]
];
$collect = collect(json_decode(json_encode($abc)));

return dd($collect->pluck('total_amount'));
```

This way you can use all collection methods like sum of all 'total_amount', if your data is like below

```
$abc =  [
    "params1" => [
        "total_amount" => "2.37",
        "user_id" => 3,
        "used_currency" => "YER"
    ],
    "params2" => [
        "total_amount" => "2.37",
        "user_id" => 3,
        "used_currency" => "YER"
    ],
];
$collect = collect(json_decode(json_encode($abc)));
return dd($collect->pluck('total_amount')->sum());
```